# weird behaviour of service and media player

Tags: java, android, service

I have an activity that starts and binds to a music playing service, hence I have implemented both the `onStartCommand` and `onBind` methods. I have a `MediaPlayer` object in the service used to play media files.

These are the steps I perform:

1. I start the service and bind to it from the activity.
2. the service invokes the `MediaPlayer` Object with a valid
   mediaLocation and the media starts playing
3. I destroy the activity, while being destroyed, I use the
   `unbindService(mServiceConn)` method to unbind to the service, the
   media keeps playing
4. I close the service, from it's close button in the notification UI,
   which calls it's `stopSelf` method, and remove the notification
   using the `notificationManager.cancel(ID)`
5. At this point, since the `service` was both `started` and `bound` I
   have called both the `unbind` and `stopSelf` methods, so acc. to the android docs
   this would be enough to stop a started-bound service.
6. The notification closes
7. and the `service`'s   `onDestroy` also gets called(checked using
   Logcat outputs)
8. yet the `MediaPlayer` keeps on playing the music

My confusion is, if the UI(activity) and notification both are destroyed, then shouldn't the whole process be destroyed, hence making the `MediaPlayer` stop? Or is the `service` not destroyed, which is why the media is still being played?

I could work around the media being played by forceFully stopping it in the `service`'s `onDestroy`  or similar methods but how do I even know the service (and the process in it's entirety) is all cleaned up? So, it's not taking up any unseen resources?

PS.: The code was too long to post a runnable example, so no code was posted, yet mostly it's just standard stuff, nothing from personal logic was added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `media player` to play music, the media player does not directly play the music, but requests the playback engine of the android system to play the music.
When you no longer use the playback engine of the android system, you should call the `release()` method of the `media player` to release system resources.